# Manipulation of Pauli Matrices

Tags: vectors

This question comes from QM but is cast as a purely mathematical question as follows:

Suppose operators $\sigma_i$ satisfy  $[\sigma_i,\sigma_j] = 2i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$ and (**n** . $\sigma)^2 = 1$  for any unit vector **n**.

Show that (**a** . $\sigma$) (**b** . $\sigma$) = **a** . **b** + i **a** x **b** . $\sigma$  for any vectors **a** and **b**.

Contracting the commutation relation with $a_i$ and $b_j$ gives some progress but I somehow cannot make use of the other condition in any meaningful way. The only way I had 'managed' to incorporate the second condition was by saying that anti-commutator {$\sigma_i$,$\sigma_j$} had to be a multiple of $\delta_{ij}$ because it is symmetric, and then contracting with $n_i$ to get the constant of proportionality. But the starting argument is false as need isotropy rather than symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

So after two more days, I found the solution to my problem;

Consider the symmetric anti-commutator $S_{ij}$  :=  {${\sigma_i, \sigma_j}$}. Contracting with $n_i$, $n_j$ and   using the given relation (**n** . $\sigma)^2 = 1$  gives $n_iS_{ij}n_j =2$ $(*)$

Choose appropriate unit vectors **n** in $(*)$ to deduce that:

{${\sigma_i, \sigma_j}$} = $2 \delta_{ij} \ $

Adding equation $[\sigma_i,\sigma_j] = 2i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$ (given) to the above yields:

${\sigma_i \sigma_j} = \delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$.

Contracting above equation with $a_i$ and $b_j$ gives the required answer.